# Is there a way to customize the notification I get in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

I currently have the Azure Devops Server connection setup with Microsoft Teams and it works fine. I get notifications for when my Build/Releases complete.

I want to know if there is a way to customize the notification I get in Microsoft Teams specifically for Builds. The notification provides the following info:
Build Pipeline Name / Build version / Status
Trigger info
and the following message-
"Build for  ABC  $/ABC/123/Development/ABC1.1, finished 06/13/2019 15:51:42 UTC"
Followed by a View Build button that takes you to that Build.

When viewing the build on the web you can see the commit msg, the dev who made the commit and the changeset number.

Is there a way to include that info in the Notification sent to Microsoft Teams? I can't find a way to edit the info included in the default notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize the notification from Azure DevOps service. If you want to, there are two options you can try:

- Submit your suggestion to Visual Studio Developer Network at [here](http://lopercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), or
- [Build your own BOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive) to notify build/release status.

Comment: Hi, agree with your opinion:-) In addition, if raise the suggestion, we may let @Mark Datoni submit it to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 since this relevant to Azure pipelines App develop team. Just for my suggestion.